# Jquery version of Ubuntu autohiding scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, animation, scrollbar

I am looking for a jquery plugin / lib to give to my developer that imitates ubuntu's autohiding scrollbar. So far, I haven't found one searching the web. Anyone know of one? Here is a demo video [at vimeo](http://vimeo.com/20523493/):

I would also like the content area to allow clicking to different points in it like you can in this plugin: [from flessler](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/localScroll/#section5c). I am only interested in the vertical, section 'click into' behavior, not the orizontal.

PS, the mousewheel still has to work, also ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of an actual plugin, but it is really not that hard to implement. Here is what I am using to show some buttons within a toolbar when the mouse enters and hide them again two seconds after the mouse left the toolbar:

```
var timeout = null;
$('#toolbar').hover(function() {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        $('.buttons', this).show();
    }, function() {
        var el = $('.buttons', this);
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        el.hide();
    }, 2000);
});

<div class="" id="toolbar">
    <ul class="buttons">
        <li>Button 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You just need to add the CSS to make it look right.

Comment: Got a demo online? I don't do HTML/CSS/JScript/Graphics. I have an allergy ;-) I do database/backend/search engine stuff.

Comment: No I don't. If you are allergic you might want to find someone who isn't. This is a fairly basic thing.